# How to return two different types of values from a method?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, concurrency, executorservice

I need to return two different types of variables (Future , ExecutorService) from a method. How can I move along?? here is the piece of code..
I have a class A and I m trying to call the run() method in 'B' class. 'startExecutorService' is the method which starts the threadExecutor and 
'stopExecutorService' is the method which stops the threadExecutor

```
 public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        A AObj= new A();

        Future<?> task = null;
        ExecutorService threadexec = null;

        task = AObj.startExecutorService(task, threadexec);

        AObj.stopExecutorService(task, threadexec);

    }

    public Future<?> startExecutorService(Future<?> control, ExecutorService threadExecutor){

        //'noOfThreads' determines the total no of threads to be created in threadpool
        int noOfThreads = 1;  

        // Creating an object for class 'B' which has the run() method
        B ThreadTaskOne   = new ExecutorServiceThreadClass();

        // Calling the ExecutorService to create Threadpool with specified number of threads
        threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

        // Creating a Future object 'control' and thereby starting the thread 'ThreadTaskOne' 
         control = threadExecutor.submit(ThreadTaskOne);    

         return control;
    }

    public void stopExecutorService(Future<?> task, ExecutorService threadExecutor){

        // Interrupting the thread created by threadExecutor
        task.cancel(true);

        if(task.isCancelled()){
            System.out.println("Task has been cancelled !!");
        }

        // Closing the threadExecutor
        threadExecutor.shutdownNow();

    }

}
```

I m getting ' NullPointerException' at 'stopExecutorService' method in line 'threadExecutor.shutdownNow();'The reason for this error is because,
the threadExecutor value is unchanged in main method.. it has changed only in 'startExecutorService' method. So I want to return the changed value
of threadExecutor back to main method, along with the Future..

Kindly help me out

Comment: I think that you may want to put some sort of hint as to the context of your problem, possibly in the tags. If this is something related to concurrency in Java, you should maybe add the tags "java", "concurrency", or "multithreading". Adding popular tags will draw more attention to your question. That being said, I don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Make a composite class and return an object of that class?

```
class A{
}

class B{
}

class Composite{
  A varA;
  B varB;
  public Composite(A ax, B by){ varA = ax; varB = by;}
  public A returnA(){ return varA;}
  public B returnB(){ return varB;}
}

class Executor{
    A a;
    B b;
 ////// code here 
    public Composite returnComposite{
     Composite c = new Composite(a,b);
     return c;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You.. But can You give me a suggestion within Class A , rather than goin for another class?? because that s my requirement.

Comment: like say. making a generic list <Fututre<?> , ExecutorService>.. and making the method to return that list.. any suggestions like that is what I m looking for